# Alternative to NSURL prefs:root link

Tags: ios

As I'm using a settings.bundle and want to make sure something is filled in before getting access to a part of my app, I need to redirect people to the Apple preferences app if this isn't filled in.

So I did a quick check if the field still has his default setting `Anoniem` and if so, showing an alert with explanation and after clicking OK, it needs to be redirected.

So here's my code:

**viewDidLoad**

```
NSString *dealerurl = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"name_preference"];
if([dealerurl compare:@"Anoniem"] == NSOrderedSame) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oeps..."
                                                      message:@"De app zal niet functioneren zonder een campaign-naam. U kunt deze aanpassen in de instellingen van uw ipad."
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

}
```

**Then the alertView:**

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General"]];
    }
}
```

We all know `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General"]];` doesn't work anymore.. So my question is:

Is there any other way of redirecting to the preferences app? Doesn't matter if it's a solution Apple will deny when uploading to the app-store, I need it for an in-house app so that wouldn't resist me from using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none, you can starting in-app preferences though.. But linking to the Apple preferences app has been deleted.